# Cakedc Users Could not load configuration file

Tags: cakephp-3.0, cakedc

I'm using [**CakeDC's Users**](https://github.com/CakeDC/users/) Plugin for authentication. 
I've followed all the steps of installation as documented **[here](https://github.com/CakeDC/users/blob/master/Docs/Documentation/Installation.md)**, but i'm getting this error:

[image]

I've performed the following steps:

1. `composer require cakedc/users`
2. `composer require league/oauth2-facebook:@stable`
3. `composer require league/oauth2-google:@stable`
4. `bin/cake migrations migrate -p CakeDC/Users`
5. In config/bootstrap.php

```js
    Configure::write('Users.config', ['users']);
    Plugin::load('CakeDC/Users', ['routes' => true, 'bootstrap' => true ]);
    Configure::write('Users.Social.login', true); //to enable social login
```

6. Load the Component in your src/Controller/AppController.php, and use
   the passed Component configuration to customize the Users Plugin:

   ```
   $this->loadComponent('CakeDC/Users.UsersAuth');
   ```

**Update:** I've removed

```
Configure::write('Users.config', ['users']);
```

this line from my bootstrap as i'm using the default users.php file which is present inside the plugin now. 
But i get this error now:

```
Invalid provider or missing class (League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\LinkedIn)
```

I can get rid of this error by disabling social login (which is not what i want to do):

```
Configure::write('Users.Social.login', false);
```

After disabling the social login i get this error:

```
Error: A route matching "array ( 'plugin' => 'CakeDC/Users', 'controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login', 'prefix' => false, '_ext' => NULL, )" could not be found.
```

Any help would save my day.

Comment: Try removing linkedIn configuration from users.php file present inside plugin.
Add Configure::write('Users.Social.login', true); inside bootstrap.php file of your application (not the plugin's bootstrap.php) to enable social login module.

Answer (score 2):

@ndm was right, Step 5 is for Configuration, when installing with composer removing the following 2 lines fixes the error before the Migration Step:

```
Configure::write('Users.config', ['users']);
Plugin::load('CakeDC/Users', ['routes' => true, 'bootstrap' => true ]);
```

Then after the migration add these lines back in to continue the installation.

Answer (score 0):

Step number 5 is customization - check the header in the docs that you've linked. So that's not actually a required installation step.

The problem should be rather easy to figure from the naming, the error that you're encountering, and the stacktrace (just check what's being done in each of the frames) - setting `Users.config` is to be used to define custom config files, the one you've defined doesn't exist (or isn't reabable), hence the error.

> ```
> collection((array)Configure::read('Users.config'))->each(function ($file) {
>     Configure::load($file);
> });
> ```

**https://github.com/CakeDC/users/blob/3.2.0/config/bootstrap.php#L21-L23**

So either don't do that and define the configuration elsewhere (being it in your `app` config, or wherever), or create the missing `users.php` config file and put your users plugin configuration in there.

See also

**[https://github.com/CakeDC/users/.../Configuration.md#overriding-the-default-configuration](https://github.com/CakeDC/users/blob/3.2.0/Docs/Documentation/Configuration.md#overriding-the-default-configuration)**

Comment: I have not created users.php file in my config/ because it is already present inside the plugin vendor/cakedc/users/config/users.php. So i just removed the line from the bootstrap.php but now the error is: 

Invalid provider or missing class (League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\LinkedIn)

Comment: I don't have installed Linkedin part of the plugin because i only want Facebook and Google auth.

Comment: I've also set social login to false so the this error is also gone, but now it says:

Error: A route matching "array ( 'plugin' => 'CakeDC/Users', 'controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login', 'prefix' => false, '_ext' => NULL, )" could not be found.